# Assigning Json object properties to a model

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm matching about 90 properties from a nested JSON-Object to a model class using dynamics and JObject.Parse:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(JsonObjectAsString);
return new Foo() {
    prop1 = json.summer.temperature,
    prop2 = json.winter.temperature,
    ...
    prop100 = json.autumn.temperature
}
```

This is very slow, but **only on the first run**. On a second run, a new JSON-Object is fetched (same structure but different values), and this one is assigned to the corresponding model properties in no time.

**Why is that? What can I do to speed up the first run?**

Edit: I've already set the build type to "Release".

Comment: You can parse your JSON object direct to model using `newtonsoft` nuget package. `var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(yourjsondata);`

Comment: The JSON object does not have the same structure as my model. Its larger and I only need some (90) properties from it. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: You can get your model class from json data from http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Ruchir, thanks for your suggestion, but I'd like to avoid adding an extra model for the external Json-Object (which might change in the future, have some new properties added etc.). The problem is that it's slow only on the FIRST run .. and I don't know why.

Comment: Ruchir, json2csharp.com is very nice, though! If no one else posts an answer, then I'll go with that.

Comment: Peter: You can convert using dynamic object as well `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);` Or without specifying model calss `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);`

Comment: If this is first run only, is the issue due to JIT building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse your JSON object direct to model using `newtonsoft` nuget package.

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(yourjsondata);
```

You can get your model class from json data from http://json2csharp.com/

You can convert using dynamic object as well

```
var objData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Or without specifying model calss

```
var objData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```