# extract model from object array using linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have an object array created from json.
each array value is an array of 2 sub arrays.
the first is of the form `["id", some integer]`
and the second being `["name", "SomeName"]`.

I want to use linq to extract these values to a class array
that has these two properties (i.e. id and name):

```
public class person
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

so the result would be of the form `person[]`.
How can it be done using linq?

help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

original json (it's really genres):

```
{"genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},
{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},   
{"id":80,"name":"Crime"},{"id":878,"name":"Science Fiction"},   
{"id":10770,"name":"TV Movie"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"},
{"id":10752,"name":"War"},{"id":37,"name":"Western"}]}
```

Then i used:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> obj = (Dictionary<string,object>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(GenresStr);
object[] genresArr = (object[])obj["genres"];
```

So genresArr has array of [[],[]], each inner [] is in the form of:
["id", some integer] and ["name", "some name"]

Comment: Can you show a sample of your object array?

Comment: And it would be good to see JSON too.

Comment: you can first Deserialize your json array to `var` and from then you can access it as simple you can do it from `List`

Comment: Hope this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/29513139/1390955

Comment: Deserializing to var is the same as to dictionary only in run time. the issue is that linq.select works with known types and here it's anonymous and with sub-arrays... trickey

Comment: As I mentioned in answer, you can first convert your json response to class using http://json2csharp.com/ and then you can have linq.select

Comment: I tried: var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieGenres>(GenresStr); but it creates an empty MovieGenre object. I need to extract the inner main value of the json and deliver it to this helper and it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not fully understand what is JSON. And another strange thing that you want to have a list of persons while your JSON contains a list of genres.

To deserialize this JSON you first need to create a corresponding model. You can always use [http://json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) for help:

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you just need one line of code. I'm using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (it's much better than `JavaScriptSerializer`) in this example:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: json2csharp made it happen! i added the correct classes it created and then:   var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(GenresStr);
                List<Genre> g = objData.genres;

Comment: marked. I'm still learning to use stackoverflow... btw, I wrtoe it as 'persons' class with no good reason, just didn't think it matters for understanding the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with SO. I recommend you to read help articles.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse your JSON object direct to model using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package.

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(jsonString);
```

You can get your model class from json data from http://json2csharp.com/

You can convert using dynamic object as well

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Or without specifying model calss

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

So your objData will be list of genres from which you can get data using simple LINQ operations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have C# arrays, you can use this **LINQ** based approach:

```
var ids = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
var names = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var personArray = ids.Zip(names, (id, name) => new Person(id, name)).ToArray();
```

Comment: didn't try this, Aleksandr's solution worked fine... ;->