# Parsing a JSON structure to an object but the structure could contain different names

Tags: c#, json

I need to be able to access the code and title properties of each shipping service but the object they're contained in is named differently each time and I don't have control of this.

[image: JSON file]

Comment: Hope this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/29513139/1390955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below use with json.net.

```
///Custom converter to parse the container.
public class ItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jobj = JObject.Load(reader);

        var item = jobj.First.First.ToObject<Item>();
        var container = new ItemContainer
        {
            Name = jobj.First.Path,
            Data = item
        };
        return container;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (Item);
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverter))]
public class ItemContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Your object is here
    public Item Data { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public class RootObj
{
    public ItemContainer[] ShippingMethods { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize json:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>("Your json string");
```

Comment: ShippingMethods is always null in this example. I have a feeling the `ReadJson` method is not being called and causing the NULL shipping methods container.

Comment: Are you sure? I success to Deserialize your json sample to object.

Comment: I made the mistake of making the methods and classes internal. It works once they're made public.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can parse your JSON object direct to model using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package.

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(jsonString);
```

You can get your model class from json data from http://json2csharp.com/

You can convert using dynamic object as well

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
```

Or without specifying model calss

```
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: I'm already using JsonConvert for deserializing other json files but cannot in this example as I don't know what the class names would be.

For example, the names "Flat" "parcelforce_48" "free" are something I don't have control of. They could be named anything. So I'm unable to create C# classes that represent their data.

Comment: Are you able to generate these classes at runtime?

Comment: Not run time, but you must know your entities else how can you fetch data from. If you go with `dynamic` then also you need to know the name of properties from which you want to access the value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Json.net` to deserialize your json into a `dynamic`variable to fix the (unknown properties) issue, and access your properties by name assuming you know them.

example:

```
dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"id\":\"123\"}");
parsedObject.id // it should read 123
```

Comment: I don't think I'm following you. In the example I've given, how would I access the object Flat's title property.

Comment: parsedObject.ShippingMethods[0].title

Comment: Doesnt appear to work, I'm getting NULL when trying to access the property.

`dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result);

var test =  parsedObject.ShippingMethods[0].title;`

Comment: `dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result);

var test =  parsedObject.ShippingMethods[0].flat;

var something = test.title;`

This example works but it relies on me knowing "Flat".